# Pass all parameters of a function

Tags: java

I have a function that receives a number of parameters.

To make my code look clearer and better to maintain, I'd like to outsource some part of the function to another function in the same class.

This new function requires the same parameters as the original function.
Is there a way to pass all parameters of this function at once (in the same order of course) instead of having to write them all explicitely?

Comment: If you often need theses parameters, maybe you should create a class with them as attributes.

Comment: Are you coming from a `Perl` background?  If so, unfortunately, there's no `&` to pass them or `@_` to grab all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have more than 3 or 4 parameters, I'd encapsulate them in an object and pass that along instead of the parameters themselves.

So, instead of

```
void someMethod(String name, int age, double salary, char gender);
```

I'd use

```
void someMethod(person);
```

with person being something like this (you get the idea)

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    double salary;
    char gender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read about var args in java. I believe this is solution which you are searching.
Here you have a little example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

While not direct answer to your question, you may try to consider creating separate class like `MyFunctionParams` witha all your params as class attributes and use object of that class to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DTO design pattern` if you have more than 3 parameters passed to the function.

`DTO` -> `Data transfer object`. 
Create an object of all the required parameters and pass it to the method.

If you don't want to create a new class then use HashMap.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
public void myMethod(Object... params){
    // method body
}
```

and then

```
myMethod(param1,param2,param3);
```

or

myMethod(param1,param2, param3, param4)

The three dots means that you are passing a variable number of parameters. Check this link  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs